# if I select No in radio button, it just showing Blank

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

There are 4 Yes,No radio buttons and if I choose Yes, it shows the value 'YES'. But, if I chooseNo, it just showing blank. May I know how can I fix it?

```
<div id='testtwo' style="display:block;">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="pnl">Is the packing properly vacuum sealed? :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin-top:19px;">
    <p class="form-control-static" style="margin-top: -7px;display: inline-flex;color: darkslategrey;">
        <input type="radio" name="pkyes" value="YES">
          <label for="pkyes" style="margin-left: 6px; margin-top: 8px;">YES</label><br>
          
        <input type="radio" name="pkyes" value="NO" style="margin-left: 16px;">
          <label for="pkno" style="margin-left: 6px; margin-top: 8px;">NO</label><br>  
    </p>
  </div></div>
```

Below is JavaScript.

```
    var testasd=document.querySelector('input[type=radio][name=pkyes]');        
if(testasd.checked == false ){
    var pk = '';
}else {
    var pk = testasd.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to check for checked. Add :checked in querySelector. Adding solution there:

```js
const testasd = document.querySelector('input[type=radio][name=pkyes]:checked');        
const pk = testasd ? testasd.value : '';
console.log(pk)
```

```html
<div id='testtwo' style="display:block;">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="pnl">Is the packing properly vacuum sealed? :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin-top:19px;">
    <p class="form-control-static" style="margin-top: -7px;display: inline-flex;color: darkslategrey;">
        <input type="radio" name="pkyes" value="YES">
          <label for="pkyes" style="margin-left: 6px; margin-top: 8px;">YES</label><br>
          
        <input type="radio" name="pkyes" value="NO" style="margin-left: 16px;" checked>
          <label for="pkno" style="margin-left: 6px; margin-top: 8px;">NO</label><br>  
    </p>
  </div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks it kinda works but if I didn't select, it says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'checked').

Comment: I have edited the answer, just need to check for testasd and if it exists, use its value. Also, that way you can use them as const for better code quality.